# Is the RJ45 boot part of the RJ45 design specification?

Tags: cable, cabling

Like tabs vs spaces, or Pokémon vs Digimon, the RJ45 boot is arguably a cause of controversy for many. Is it, however, in the official design specification for the RJ45 connector, or is it a non-standard addition?

The existence of so many boot designs could suggest that it is non-standard; some are just a tab, others an all-encompassing shroud. Unfortunately, I have been unable to find conclusive evidence to support or dismiss this hypothesis.

- [RJ45 Connectors – What You Need to Know](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/rj45-connectors-what-you-need-to-know)
- [A Guide to RJ45 Connectors](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=ideas-and-advice/rj45-connectors-guide)
- [RJ45 or 8P8C Connectors? Finding the True Ethernet Standard](https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/rj45-connectors)
- [Introducing RJ45 Cat6A plug](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7F1-1773852-6_RJ45_CAT6A_FLYER%7F0916%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_1-1773852-6_RJ45_CAT6A_FLYER_0916.pdf%7F2120892-1)
- [What is an RJ45 connector?](https://www.liveelectronicsgroup.com/news-blog/what-is-an-rj45-connector/)

For example, was the design team behind [FN - 63697](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/field-notices/636/fn63697.html) just following the official RJ45 specification?

Just to be clear, I am referring specifically to the RJ45 connector, not the cable that it carries.

---

NE was suggested by [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384248/371745).

Comment: You've already answered your own question... if it were a standard, everyone would be making the same thing -- the thing spelled out in the standard. That's not the case -- there are hundreds of different (patented even!) ways to protect the "RJ45" (RJ48/8P8C) connector.

Answer (score 4):

IEEE 802.3 twisted-pair Ethernet uses the 8P8C modular connector standardized in IEC 60603-7. The "RJ45" name is almost ubiquitous but there's no official standard of that name. There's only an [RJ45S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ45S) registered jack (keyed 8P2C) that's wired differently.

Any modifications, protective boot, shroud, bend protection etc. are not standardized by IEEE or IEC, but they may be present in industrial or military standards.

You can get the full Ethernet specs on the [IEEE GET](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68) page (free after registration). Sadly, IEC standards are not freely available.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am referring to the connector only, not the cable.

Comment: Me neither. ;-)

Comment: Then why are you talking about the Ethernet standards?

Comment: Where else do you use an "RJ45" connector? That's on topic here?

Comment: In their comment on the question, Ron Maupin pointed out that RJ45 is not specifically an Ethernet connector.

Comment: Since "RJ45" isn't really specified *anywhere* short of what's in common use, I'd venture that "RJ45" implies Ethernet use. The generic term is 8P8C. However, any other use than for networking is off topic here, so if you're after the mechanical/electrical details, [electronics.se] might be a better site to ask.

Comment: For all you trivia buffs, the designation **Registered Jack 45** (S) was created by Bell Labs to specify a standard connector for modem and data interfaces.  The specific type has a "key" to prevent other use, and has different wiring than what is used today.  But the name stuck, just like the "Return" key on your keyboard.  [Here's more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ45S).

Comment: That is both interesting and frustrating. I would have thought there would be an ISO or IEEE standard for it. Thanks though!